# Rapid procedure to construct an analytic function from a real part

Tags: complex-analysis, cauchy-riemann-equations

I have this rapid procedure  to construct an analytic function from a real part:

\begin{equation}
u(x,y)=e^x(cosy-siny)
\end{equation}

We have the partial derivatives:
\begin{equation}
\begin{array}
fu_x=e^x(cosy-siny) \\
u_y=e^x(-siny-cosy) \\
\end{array}
\end{equation}

So by the Cauchy-Riemann equations we want to find the complex conjugate function, v:
\begin{equation}
\begin{array}
fu_x=v_y \\
u_y=-v_x
\end{array}
\end{equation}

By the first relation (eqn 1):

\begin{equation}
v(x,y)=\int e^x(cosy-siny)dx= e^x(cosy-siny)+h(y)
\end{equation}

We find h(y) by the second relation

\begin{equation}
\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\big[e^x(cosy-siny)+h(y)\big]=-e^x(-cosy-siny)
\end{equation}

Integrate both sides and obtain

\begin{equation}
\big[e^x(cosy-siny)+h'(x,y)\big]=e^x(cosy+siny) 
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
h'(x,y)=e^x(cosy+siny) -e^x(cosy-siny)
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
h'(x,y)=2e^xsiny
\end{equation}

Then we integrate with respect to x and obtain

\begin{equation}
\int h'(x,y)dx=\int 2e^xsiny dx= 2e^xsiny
\end{equation}

Insert in the equation nr 1 above for $h(y)$ and multiply it by *i*

\begin{equation}
v(x,y)=e^x(cosy-siny)+2ie^xsiny
\end{equation}

Would this be correct, and accurate?

Thanks

Comment: you mean harmonic conjugate?

Comment: Yes, I correct.

Comment: Both $u$ and $v$ and *real-valued* functions, there should not be a factor $i$ in the result.

Comment: Btw, a more rapid method would be to put a magic pair of glasses on and “see” $e^x(\cos y-\sin y)$ as the real part of $(1+i)e^z$

Comment: @MartinR I see the error you mention. Corrected

Comment: Hi Martin, not that I forgot to integrate h'(x,y) at the end. I did it just now. But I am note sure, should it be integrated with respect to x or y? Since the previous step was differentiation with respect to x, I suppose the integration should be with respect to x.